# Window Cmd Prompt - Move file with special character

Tags: window, cmd, prompt

i got a file by the filename

```
[vvv]_PHØDE：GREAKER_-_01_[720p][10bit][z11].mkv
```

how do i move the file with the move command at command prompt to make it this way

```
move "*GREAKER*.mkv" "PHODE_GREAKER_-_01_[720p][10bit][z11].mkv"
```

i want the second * to be replace at the destination as _-*01*[720p][10bit][z11] after the breaker.

In linux we can use regex pattern like (*.?) something like this , but how do i move it at window.

to take away this `[vvv]_PHØDE：and make it as the string "PHODE"`

Answer (score 0):

On windows, MOVE is mainly used to move a file from one folder to another. It can only rename the file if the MOVE command is operating on a single file. If you are using wildcards in your source file then you should use REN (or RENAME) instead.

But, you have another problem that is more problematic. You have the `:` character in your file name, which is not valid for Windows. This may be impossible to fix with standard Windows commands and utilities. Perhaps one of the following SuperUser links can help:

- [How to batch rename files copied from OSX to Windows with ':' in filenames?](https://superuser.com/q/49679/109090)
- [How to force Windows XP to rename a file with a special character?](https://superuser.com/q/31587/109090)
- [Files with illegal filenames](https://superuser.com/q/90227/109090)

Comment: Fortunately he doesn't have a "normal" colon in the filename, but a fullwidth colon (unicode character `U+FF1A`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Ahhh... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%f in (*GREAKER*.mkv) do (
  set name=%%~f
  ren "%%~f" "PHODE_!name:~12!"
)

endlocal
```